# Accessing listview item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am using list view and i want to get the id column value?
when i use selected item, it gave me collection of all the columns value ?
Could anyone help how to achieve that ?

note:
I am using wpf with linq to sql

```
private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView d = (ListView)sender;   
    var q = d.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(q.ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `SelectedItem` to your data-type, i.e.

```
var data = (MyClass)d.SelectedItem;
// Do something with data.ID or whatever the ID-property is called.
```

Comment: Could you give me example regarding using listView.ItemContainerGenerator

Comment: I use the following but how could get each field ?  
            ListViewItem a = (ListViewItem)ListView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListView1.SelectedItem);

Comment: @user1176554: I misread your question, you do not need the UI-elements of your column, you just need to cast the `SelectedItem`, see edited answer.